# Using many selector in drawable performance is decrease

Tags: android, button

In my android application have many buttons each button have different selector. Suppose i use more than 50 `selector.xml` it will decrease the application performance. Please give your valuable suggestion.

Thanks,

Comment: How did you measured that it will decrease the application performance?

Comment: Don't know just asking your suggestion..